# How does the gradle --project-cache-dir work in mult-project and composite build project?

Tags: java, gradle

As per my understanding with gradle, every project has .gradle folder at project root for caching some data like checksum etc. and this location can be changed with --project-cache-dir. so it should be project specific property.

I am currently working on gradle composite build project. when I set this property and submitted full build I am getting compile error but without the property compilation is successful.

How exactly this works in composite build and multi build projects?

Comment: what is the value used ? Is that absolute path or "directory name"?

Comment: Is there a small code (git hub?) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: its an absolute path --project-cache-dir /tmp/.gradle-project-cache

Comment: In composite build each child project is a full gradle project. May be mixing them in one  is removing previous projects output?